# Tcl Error in Tkinter "Invalid command name"

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build an IA with a graphic interface with Tkinter, but when i'm running my code, write something into the User space and press Enter, i got this error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ilan\Desktop\Python\ProjetIa\IA 2.0\GUI.pyw", line 53, in Enter_pressed
    self.text.config(state='normal')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1270, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1261, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".56241624.56241736"
```

This is my code

GUI :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

input_get = ""
ia_answers = ""

class TextFrame(Frame):
   def __init__(self, window, **kwargs):
    """Init the main top frame who contains the discussion"""
    LabelFrame.__init__(self, window, text="Discussion",borderwidth = 15, height = 200, width = 200)
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP, expand = True)

    # Font options
    self.printopt = font.Font(family = "Times")

    # Create the Text widget, who contains the discussion, it is append by the Enter_pressed function
    self.text = Text(self, state='disabled', bg ="grey")
    self.text.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True, side = "left")

    # Tag for the justify options on the text
    self.text.tag_configure("right", justify="right", font=self.printopt)
    self.text.tag_configure("left", justify="left", font=self.printopt)

    # Put the Scrollbar and his options
    self.scr = Scrollbar(self)
    self.scr.config(command=self.text.yview)
    self.text.config(yscrollcommand=self.scr.set)
    self.scr.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)

class InputFrame(TextFrame):
  def __init__(self, window, **kwargs):
    """Init the main bottom frame who contains the user input box """

    # Import the parent class (Textframe)modules
    TextFrame.__init__(self,window)
    LabelFrame.__init__(self, window, text="User :", borderwidth=4)
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

    # Create the input box for the user
    self.input_user = StringVar()
    self.input_field = Entry(self)
    self.input_field.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

    def Enter_pressed(event):
     """Took the current string in the Entry field.""" 
     # Take the globals variables
     global input_get
     global ia_answers
     # Take the input of the user in the input box
     self.input_get = self.input_field.get()
     self.input_field.delete(0, 1000)
     # Put the text in state normal then add the variables finally put it in disabled mode
     self.text.config(state='normal')
     self.text.insert("end", "\n"+input_get+"\n", "left")
     self.text.insert("end", "\n"+ia_answers+"\n", "right")
     self.text.config(state='disabled')
     # Scroll automatically to the bottom of the window
     self.text.yview(END)
    self.input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
```

And this is my mainscript

Mainscript :

```
import GUI
from GUI import *
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
TextFrame(window)
InputFrame(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.
Ilan

Comment: inside `TextFrame.__init__` you have to call `Frame.__init__`, not `LabelFrame.__init__` because you define `class TextFrame(Frame)`. Inside `InputFrame.__init__` you have to call only `TextFrame.__init__` because you declare `class InputFrame(TextFrame)`

Comment: I've tried and it's not looking like it should, i've got two frame and a input box apart.

Comment: your classes look wierd - all this `__init__`. If you need `LabelFrame` in other class you can call `LabelFrame(...)`.

Comment: is `Enter_pressed(event)` parts of `InputFrame` class ?

Comment: I know but it's an old code that i have found, yes it's a part of InputFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are constructing your classes incorrectly. Look at this code:

```
class TextFrame(Frame):
   def __init__(self, window, **kwargs):
    ...
    LabelFrame.__init__(self, window, text="Discussion",borderwidth = 15, height = 200, width = 200)
    ...
```

You are inheriting from `Frame`, but are calling the constructor of `LabelFrame`. This is not causing your problem, but it is incorrect and should be fixed. You need to either inherit from `LabelFrame`, or call the `Frame` constructor.

Also, take a look at this code:

```
class InputFrame(TextFrame):
  def __init__(self, window, **kwargs):
    ...
    TextFrame.__init__(self,window)
    LabelFrame.__init__(self, window, text="User :", borderwidth=4)
    ...
```

In the above code, you inherit from `TextFrame` and correctly call the constructor for `TextFrame`, but you *also* call the constructor for `LabelFrame`. That call to `LabelFrame.__init__` is what is causing your `invalid command name` error. You need to remove that line of code.

However, it's not clear if you really intend to inherit from `TextFrame`, or if you intend to inherit from `LabelFrame`. Whichever one you inherit from, you need to call that class's `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I press Enter I've got an _Attribute Error :  'InputFrame' object has no attribute 'text'_. I've tried multiple things but it doesn't seems to work, the answer it's surely just in front of me but I can't see it.

Comment: @IlanRossler: that's a completely different problem. The error should be self-explanatory.  Your `InputText` class clearly has no attribute named `text`.

Comment: :So, how can I acces to the text widget who is in the other class ? If I wrote `class InputFrame(TextFrame)` why can't I acces to it ?

Comment: And even if i write `TextFrame.text.config(state='normal')` it says `AttributeError: type object 'TextFrame' has no attribute 'text'`.

Comment: @IlanRossler: don't just keep throwing code at the problem. Think about what the error is telling you.What objects have a `text` attribute? Do you have access to those objects? This isn't a tkinter problem, it's just a normal problem of variable scope with python.

Comment: Ok I will think about all of that, thanks for your help and your time.